# A reference to pojo in Android is lost during onClick event

Tags: android, image, onclick, pojo

I'm developing a small game where I have images that changes and a control panel (some buttons) which the user suppose to press them according to the shown image. The GameView class extends SurfaceView so when the activity starts it just create the game and set the content view (a layout with SurfaceView and some buttons in relative layout). The game call loadGameObjects during setSurfaceSize callback as follow:

```java
public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height)  
{  
 synchronized (holder)  
 {  
  canvasWidth = width;  
  canvasHeight = height;  
  GameView.this.postInvalidate();  
  loadGameObjects(getResources());  
 }
```

}
In loadGameObjects method i keep a reference to a game pojo object which is not a view (but holds references to images) as follow:

```
public void loadGameObjects(Resources resouces)  
{ 
 List<GameObject> gameObjects = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
 int middleX = getWidth()/2;
 int middleY = getHeight()/2;
 //Create the backgroung game object
 BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable)resouces.getDrawable(R.drawable.g_monitor);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background.getBitmap(), getWidth(), 
            getHeight(), true);
 background = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
 gameObjects.add(new GameObject(this, getContext(), background, new Point(0,0)));
 //Create the game object with all its images.
 Map<RunningGoblinResourceEnum, BitmapDrawable> goblinImgs = new HashMap<RunningGoblinResourceEnum, BitmapDrawable>();
 goblinImgs.put(RunningGoblinResourceEnum.greenGoblinUp, (BitmapDrawable)resouces.getDrawable(R.drawable.goblin_up_green));
 //This map get more entries like this...

 //ourGoblin is a member var that later will be null in onClick
 ourGoblin = new RunningGoblinObject(this, getContext(), goblinImgs, 
            new Point(middleX, middleY));
 gameObjects.add(ourGoblin);
 setGameObjects(gameObjects); 
}
```

During doDraw the game objects "draw" method is called to draw themself on the canvas.
My problem is that when I click the button the reference to **ourGoblin** game object is null although it was valid during loadGameObjects method.
Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: can you show the code of onclick listener?

Answer (score 1):

I had something simillar.
In loadGameObjects method you create ourGoblin instance using the new operator. However, if this is a view in a layout which was used with setContentView the system does not relate your view to the view in the layout and thus from the system point of view the view in the layout is still null until findViewById will be called with this view id. Try to call findViewById on that id and see if ourGoblin is still null, if not then take in mind that you still have two instances of that object, one created using the new operator and one by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
You can see that it is a very simple and straight forward onClick implementation:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
 Log.d(getClass().getName() + "onClick", "ourGoblin = " + ourGoblin);
 if(ourGoblin == null)
  return;
 Log.d(getClass().getName() + "onClick", "ourGoblin = " + ourGoblin.getCurrentImageEnum().toString());
 int id = v.getId();
 switch(id)
 {
 case R.id.greenUp:
  if(RunningGoblinResourceEnum.greenGoblinUp.equals(ourGoblin.getCurrentImageEnum()))
  {
   //Do something to statistics
  }
  break;
 }
}
```

and also my layout xml file is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gameFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.test.game.GameView android:id="@+id/gameView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/controlPanel" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <Button android:id="@+id/greenUp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="up"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Another interesting finding:
I add a member var `private Object test;` and initiate it in loadGameObjects method right after the initialization of **ourGoblin** var - it was also null in onClick method. However when I initialize it at the deceleration line as follow: `private Object test = new Object();` it is not null in onClick method!!! Any idea why?